# Find all pairs of disjoint subsets of list

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

Given a set $E$, how can I find all pairs of subsets $E_1, E_2$ which are non empty and disjoint? I don't care the order of $E_1, E_2$.

Right now I use a bit complicated code. First find all partitions, and the choose subsets from them.

```
partition[elist_] := Module[{lengthsAll},
  lengthsAll = 
   Flatten[Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Length[elist]], 1];
  FoldPairList[TakeDrop, elist, #] & /@ lengthsAll
  ]

e0e2[elist_] := Module[{part},
  part = partition[elist] // Select[#, Length[#] >= 2 &] &;
  part = Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ part // Flatten[#, 1] &
  ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Select[Apply[DisjointQ]] @ Subsets[Subsets[#, {1, ∞}], {2}] &;

f[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{{a}, {b}}, {{a}, {c}}, {{a}, {b, c}}, {{b}, {c}}, {{b}, {a, c}}, {{c}, {a, b}}}
> ```

**Note:** This is not quite the same as the list produced by OP's `e0e2`:

```
Sort @ e0e2[{a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {{{a}, {b}}, {{a}, {c}}, {{a}, {b, c}}, {{b}, {c}}, {{a, b}, {c}}}
> ```

Comment: I see, I made a mistake and missed one.